# What data is available to estimate cost of ownership and reliability for potential car purchases

Tags: canada, car

I am currently shopping for a used vehicle.  I am hoping to spend between $10,000 and $16,000 CAD and looking for something that will be reliable and low cost.

My current vehicle is a 2009 Mazda 3.  When I bought it, the car was around 3 years old with 70,000km on it.  It is now 11 years old with 200,000km on it.  My mechanic has advised me that I have around $2000 of repairs and that I should look for a new car.

When I purchased my last car, I used the [Lemonade series of books](http://lemonaidcars.com/about.html) to evaluate different options.  In the book, the author does an in-depth analysis of every car's reliability, costs, safety, etc.  Unfortunately, this resource isn't published anymore.

The main question I am trying to solve is "What car should I buy".  In order to address this question, I am interested in answering these questions:

- What will the cost of owning  for 10 years.
- How much effort will it be to maintain?  How frequently will I be stranded?

I have looked at:

- [CAA Driving Costs Calculator](https://carcosts.caa.ca/) - This seems to provide interesting data.  One limitation is that estimated costs are for a 5 year period.  I am interested in reliability over a longer window.
- [Edmonds Cost of Car Ownership](https://www.edmunds.com/tco.html) - Problem with this data is that it is US-centric.  Car costs vary quite largely between Canada and the US.  Additionally, in Quebec we have difficult winters and salt our roads which introduces different maintenance problems.

Comment: I don't know the answer but if I have a question I'll be asking you.  You already know the insurance, parking, registration, fuel and approx. maintenance costs for that class of car, use, and location.  The difference between that and a civic or cruze etc. is a coin toss.

Comment: @brian - I have some data for those things, but I am unsure of the reliability of the data provided by CAA & Edmonds.  I am also unsure whether a 5 year time-frame will translate cleanly to a 10 year time-frame or if there are other things that I should be considering, but am not.